# Error of incorrect type in MIPS

Tags: loops, assembly, mips, string-comparison

I am getting an "operand of incorrect type" error for the following code at the line where I try to load the individual characters. I am trying to write a program that inputs two strings and compares them (i.e. prints if one is greater than or less than or equal to the other). I want to use a loop to load each letter until either a GT or LT is found, or alternatively, at the end I would know they are equal. Any help would be appreciated!

```
.data
prompt1: .asciiz "Enter string 1: "
prompt2: .asciiz "Enter string 2: "
gthan: .asciiz "s1 > s2\n"
lthan: .asciiz "s1 < s2\n"
equalto: .asciiz "The strings are equal\n"
s1size: .word 80
s2size: .word 80
s1: .space 20
s2: .space 20

.text
main:
# read in strings
li $v0, 4 
la $a0, prompt1 
syscall
li $v0, 8 #read in string
la $a0, s1 
lw $a1, s1size
move $s0, $a0 #move to s0
syscall

li $v0, 4 
la $a0, prompt2 
syscall
li $v0, 8 #read in string
la $a0, s2 
lw $a1, s2size
move $s1, $a0 #move to s1
syscall 


li $a0, 0 #set sentinel
start_loop:
#load single character
la $t0, s1
lb $a1, $a0($t0)
la $t0, s2
lb $a2, $a0($t0)
#compare
bgt $a1, $a2, greaterthan
blt $a1, $a2, lessthan
beq $a1, $a2, equal
addi $a0, $a0, 4
end_loop:


greaterthan: 
li $v0, 4 
la $a0, gthan 
syscall

lessthan:
li $v0, 4 
la $a0, gthan 
syscall

equal:
li $v0, 4 
la $a0, equalto 
syscall
```

Comment: `$a0($t0)` <-- That's not a valid addressing mode. Add the two registers into another free register and use that. Also, consult a MIPS instruction set reference.

Comment: And please don't give labels names like `s1` and `s2`, since they look extremely similar to the registers `$s1` and `$s2`.

Comment: @Michael I can see that it's not the correct way to refer to the address, but my question is what is the right way? I've only ever had to do this using a specific value (for example 32($t0) ), so I'm not sure how to do this now that it depends on a variable. I already tried using a reference card, but am still stuck on this. Thanks.

Comment: Use an `addu` instruction to generate the address in another temporary register.  MIPS only has one addressing mode (register+imm16), so everything else requires extra instructions for address-generation.

Comment: basically you may want to set `$t0 = address of s1` and `$t1 = address of s2` ahead of loop, then during loop `addiu $t0, $t0, 1` and `addiu $t1, $t1, 1` to increment the addresses, and then you compare one of the addresses for end to terminate loop. But it would make sense to put zero terminator after both inputted strings (or verify if the simulator doesn't end them with `<EOL>`), so when you reach terminating address (and all characters were equal up to that point, including the terminators), you know the strings are equal. Without terminator you risk situation: `0 == strcmp("a", "ab")`.

Comment: And the rest of your code is unfinished and wrong in some aspects, like incrementing `a0` by 4, while you operate over bytes (+1 only needed), and `s1size` is `80`, but you reserve only 20 bytes of space for the input, so user can overwrite memory beyond that with long input, etc... (the terminating address above is `s1 + length_of_input_including_terminator_byte` -> that makes it safe to not check for `s2` terminator, because either it will be reached sooner than `s1` and the loop will end by detecting `<` or `>` situation (strings are different), or end address reached = strings are equal.